# Mat Autocomplete does not display data after service call

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a autocomplete field which should fetch data from a service call, the service call is working fine and i am able to assign data to my autocomplete variable in the class, But the autocomplete does not show any options on the app.

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field id="numberField" appearance="outline">
   <mat-label>Enter a Number</mat-label>
   <input matInput placeholder="Enter Number" [formControl]="numberControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" required>
 <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let number of (filteredNumbers$ | async)" [value]="number">{{number}}</mat-option>
 </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS**

```
filteredNumbers$: Observable<Array<Number>> = null;
numberControl = new FormControl();

this.filteredNumbers$ = this.numberControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(300),
  switchMap(value => {
    return this.getNumbers(value);
  })
)



getNumbers(filterValue: string) :Observable<Array<Number>> {

      return this.numberService.getNumbers(filterValue)

    }
```

**Service**

```
 getNumbers(payload: string) {
    return this.http
      .post<Array<Number>>(`${this.baseUrl}/api/numbers/allNumbers`, payload );
  }
```

**Error**

```
ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:41)
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/switchMap.js.SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (switchMap.js:51)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/switchMap.js.SwitchMapSubscriber._next (switchMap.js:41)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:53)
    at DebounceTimeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/debounceTime.js.DebounceTimeSubscriber.debouncedNext (debounceTime.js:48)
    at AsyncAction.dispatchNext (debounceTime.js:62)
    at AsyncAction.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/scheduler/AsyncAction.js.AsyncAction._execute (AsyncAction.js:64)
    at AsyncAction.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/scheduler/AsyncAction.js.AsyncAction.execute (AsyncAction.js:52)
    at AsyncScheduler.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/scheduler/AsyncScheduler.js.AsyncScheduler.flush (AsyncScheduler.js:43)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1673
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1719
next @ core.js:4311
schedulerFn @ core.js:3551
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:194
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:132
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:76
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:53
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:3535
(anonymous) @ core.js:3842
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:150
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:3779
onHandleError @ core.js:3842
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:395
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:198
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:498
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:487
timer @ zone.js:2281
setInterval (async)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2302
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:301
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:404
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:238
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:261
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:1245
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2317
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1569
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/scheduler/AsyncAction.js.AsyncAction.requestAsyncId @ AsyncAction.js:35
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/scheduler/AsyncAction.js.AsyncAction.schedule @ AsyncAction.js:28
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Scheduler.js.Scheduler.schedule @ Scheduler.js:13
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/scheduler/AsyncScheduler.js.AsyncScheduler.schedule @ AsyncScheduler.js:31
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/debounceTime.js.DebounceTimeSubscriber._next @ debounceTime.js:36
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:53
schedulerFn @ core.js:3551
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:194
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:132
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:76
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:53
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:3535
push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity @ forms.js:2493
push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControl.setValue @ forms.js:2828
updateControl @ forms.js:1742
(anonymous) @ forms.js:1727
push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/autocomplete.es5.js.MatAutocompleteTrigger._handleInput @ autocomplete.es5.js:738
(anonymous) @ ReplaceNumberComponent.html:112
handleEvent @ core.js:10251
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:11344
debugHandleEvent @ core.js:11047
dispatchEvent @ core.js:7710
(anonymous) @ core.js:8154
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:988
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:423
onInvokeTask @ core.js:3811
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:422
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:195
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:498
invokeTask @ zone.js:1744
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1770
```

I have changed the code according to some suggestions and getting a new error.

Comment: Show how exactly you are declaring and assigning value to `numbers`. You are looping over numbers in the template but you don’t seem to be setting the value to Observable<T>.

Comment: Hey Alexander, that was a mistake it should have been filteredNumbers instead of numbers, edited the post

Comment: What are you piping via the async (this subscribes for you) pipe and subscribing in your ts component? Do one or the other. Assuming you want RxJS stream you may also need brackets `let number of (filteredNumbers$ | async)` with `filteredNumbers$ = this.numberControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(300),
  switchMap(value => {
    return this.getNumbers(value);
  })
)`.

Comment: Hey Andrew, i modified my code according to your suggestion(edited the question too)  and i am getting a new error.

Comment: @NihalReddy See this stackblitz and let me know if this answers what you were looking for - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so57914353-autocomplete-stream

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks for the update and yes this is what i was looking for but as i said before following your directions did not resolve the issue